# Bounding the dimensions of faithful representations of a quotient group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, unitary-representations

For $G$ a compact Lie group, let $\operatorname{mdfr}(G)$ be the  minimum dimension of a faithful complex representation of $G$. Is there a bound on $\operatorname{mdfr}(N(H)/H)$ for $H$ a subgroup of $U(n)$ with normalizer $N(H)$?

Comment: You mean, a bound depending on $H$? or a bound depending on $n$ only (i.e., describe the supremum over $H\le U(n)$ of the values $\mathrm{mdfr}(N(H)/H)$)?

Comment: I am looking for the existence of a uniform bound depending only on n and independent of H.

Comment: $H$ is a closed subgroup?  Closed and connected?

Comment: @LSpice I'm pretty sure $H$ is assumed closed, but not assumed connected.

Comment: The answer would be "yes" if the following stronger fact would hold: the number of components of $N(H)$ is bounded when $H$ ranges over closed subgroups of $U(n)$. Is this true? I see no obvious obstruction ($H$ finite would be a good starting point).

Comment: Yes, H is closed but not necessarily connected.

Comment: How does that follow?